# Android + NDK пересобрать проект

Tags: android, android-ndk, build

У меня MacOS, Android Studio и проект NDK.

Вношу изменения в код C++, но он не отрабатывает, говорят что надо пересобрать проект для этого.

Никогда не работал с NDK, как пересобрать проект, чтобы все вносимые изменения в С++ применялись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете Android Studio тогда: `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Странно, но почему то внесенные изменения в файлы C++ не отрабатывают. Я закомментировал одну функцию, но она продолжает отрабатывать.

Comment: Попробуйте Build -> Clean Project а потом уже Build -> Build Project

Comment: А еще возможно у вас Instant Run включен, если включен - отключите